# Message to Websphere MQ doesn't receive reply (Fuse ESB 7.1)

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, ibm-mq, fuseesb

I'm sending a "RequestSnapshot" to a Websphere-MQ queue which is define by the vendor as 'S' (synchronous) - so I am expecting to receive a reply via the Apache Camel `inOut` integration pattern, running in Fuse ESB.

```
from("direct:" + SEND_SUBSCRIPTION)
        .routeId(getFinalRouteName(SEND_SUBSCRIPTION))
        .log("Sending Request Snapshot request to webspheremq")
        .bean(CreateSnapshotRequest.class)
        .marshal(myDataFormat)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .inOut("webspheremq:queue:SNAPSHOT_REQUESTS.HT")   // **1** works, but no Reply!!
        .log("RequestSnapshot response: ${body}")          // doesnt reach this line
```

I know that the snapshot request message is transmitted correctly, because after I send it I receive a data on a different MQ topic.

The problem is that I am not receiving a response, the execution stops on the line marked `**1**` - and after 20 seconds I get a timeout.

```
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received
within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID:
Camel-ID-XYZ012-54037-1385986757895-0-3 not received.
```

Normally, via java code, this would be done differently, but here we are using `Fuse ESB` and the `inOut` mechanism should send the message and get a reply on what is called the `DYNAMIC REPLY-TO QUEUE`.

My understanding of the "reply-to" queue is somewhat limited, I just understand that Fuse ESB should listen for a response on some sort of temporary mq, but that this should work transparently via `inOut`.

Here is my configuration bean from `blueprint.xml`:

```
<bean id="webspheremq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
            <property name="hostName" value="1.2.3.4"/>
            <property name="port" value="1417"/>
            <property name="channel" value="SOME.CHANNEL"/>
            <property name="temporaryModel" value="SOME_MODEL_QUEUE"/>
            <property name="CCSID" value="789"/>
            <property name="queueManager" value="SOMEGATE"/>
            <property name="brokerSubQueue" value="SYSTEM.JMS.ND.MACHINE.USER.*"/>
            <property name="brokerControlQueue" value="SOME_SUBSCRIPTION.HT"/>
            <property name="brokerQueueManager" value="SOMEHUB"/>
            <property name="tempQPrefix" value="MACHINE.USER.*"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The other question in my mind is firewall ports, we asked to open 1417 and 1499, but only 1417 seems to be open. Plus I do not know if the firewall ports are open in the opposite direction, from WebsphereMQ back to me.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone can offer any advice!

**Edit 1:**

I tried the `replyTo=queue:XYZ` suggestion from Claus, and the result was like this:

```
2013-12-03 14:38:04,636 | WARN  | eplyManager[FOO] | entQueueMessageListenerContainer
| ?                                   ? | 153 - org.springframework.jms - 
3.0.7.RELEASE |     Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'FOO'
- trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ; nested exception is 
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2085
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named reply queues also. Maybe that works better with WMQ. So in the Camel endpoint uri, you just set replyTo=queue:foobar to use the queue named foobar as the reply queue.

That would set the JMSReplyTo header as foobar as the queue name, so the "other side" would use that for reply queue, instead of a temporary queue name.

See the Camel JMS documentation for more details about request/reply over JMS as there is many options you can configure and tweak: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Also in the past WMQ didn't link long correlation ids, and the option useMessageIDAsCorrelationID can be set to true, to use the message id that WMQ generated for the request message. Otherwise a long random id is generated by Camel.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I'll try that when I return to office tomorrow.

Comment: I tried `replyTo=queue:FOO` in various ways (e.g. with a prefix similar to my tempQName) and it couldn't set up the queue (see edit), I had a MQException. Then with `useMessageIDAsCorrelationID` the result was the same - timeout after 20000 millis. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The final solution to this was to configure the queue uri with `deliveryPersistent=1` and `useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true`.

Comment: And regarding correlation ID's, WMQ has a weird method of sending back a string prefaced with `ID:` and containing the Ascii character codes of the first 24 characters of the Correlation Id you sent. If you do this conversion yourself first (as I presume `useMessageIDAsCorrelationID` does for you) then you get the same Correlation id back (as intended).